# Can I use Discriminator on iBatis with subMap value = "X" and subMap value = "!X"?

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, ibatis

I have an Address component and I want a different behavior whether the country is Romania or not.

I want something like:

```
<resultMap class="Address" id="one" resultMap="commonFieldsMap">
    <discriminator column="COUNTRY" javaType="int">
        <subMap value="123" resultMap="romania"/>
        <subMap value="!123" resultMap="foreign"/>
    </discriminator>
</resultMap>
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out you can create a `typeHandler` and apply there an `if` and you return `0` or `1`, values which you put in `subMap value`.

```
<discriminator javaType="CountryType" column="COUNTRY" typeHandler="CTHandler">
```